# how can I insert a line break in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    let today = new Date();
    let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
    let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
    let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");
    var selectedCell  =' d';
    
    let btn=document.getElementById("button");
    let btnTag=document.getElementById("buttonTag");

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td').forEach(e1 => {
        if(e1.className === 'bg-success'){
            e1.innerHTML += document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;

        }
    });
    });
    //btn.addEventListener("click",getText);

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"];

    let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);



    function next() {
        currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
        currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

    function previous() {
        currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
        currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

    function jump() {
        currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
        currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

  

    function showCalendar(month, year) {

        let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
        let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

        let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

        // clearing all previous cells
        tbl.innerHTML = " ";
        // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
        monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
        selectYear.value = year;
        selectMonth.value = month;

        // creating all cells
        let date = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // creates a table row
            let row = document.createElement("tr");

            //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
            for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                    

                    let cell = document.createElement("td");
                    let cellText = document.createTextNode(" ");
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    
                    row.appendChild(cell);


                }
                else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    let cell = document.createElement("td");
                    let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                    if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                        cell.classList.add("bg-success");
                    } // color today's date
                    

                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    date++;
                }


            }

            tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td')
.forEach(e =>{ 
    e.addEventListener("click", adddevnt)});
    }
    function adddevnt(e) {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
    document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td').forEach(e1 => {
        e1.className='';
    });
   e.target.classList.add("bg-success");

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kalender</title>
    <p></p>
    <H1 align="center" style="font-size:80px;" style="font-family: Arial, Verdana;" ;"  ><span style="color: white;"</span><i>Kalender</i></H1></span>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">


<html><head><title>background-color</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color:rgba(34, 65, 20, 0.911); font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; font-size:100%; }
</style>
</head>
</html>
          

</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container col-sm-4 col-md-7 col-lg-6 mt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>So</th>
                <th>Mo</th>
                <th>Di</th>
                <th>Mi</th>
                <th>Do</th>
                <th>Fr</th>
                <th>Sa</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="calendar-body">

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-inline">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="previous" onclick="previous()">Zurück</button>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="next" onclick="next()">Nächster</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Wechsel zu: </label>
            <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">
                <option value=0>Jan</option>
                <option value=1>Feb</option>
                <option value=2>Mär</option>
                <option value=3>Apr</option>
                <option value=4>Mai</option>
                <option value=5>Jun</option>
                <option value=6>Jul</option>
                <option value=7>Aug</option>
                <option value=8>Sep</option>
                <option value=9>Okt</option>
                <option value=10>Nov</option>
                <option value=11>Dez</option>
            </select>


            <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year" onchange="jump()">
            <option value=1990>1990</option>
            <option value=1991>1991</option>
            <option value=1992>1992</option>
            <option value=1993>1993</option>
            <option value=1994>1994</option>
            <option value=1995>1995</option>
            <option value=1996>1996</option>
            <option value=1997>1997</option>
            <option value=1998>1998</option>
            <option value=1999>1999</option>
            <option value=2000>2000</option>
            <option value=2001>2001</option>
            <option value=2002>2002</option>
            <option value=2003>2003</option>
            <option value=2004>2004</option>
            <option value=2005>2005</option>
            <option value=2006>2006</option>
            <option value=2007>2007</option>
            <option value=2008>2008</option>
            <option value=2009>2009</option>
            <option value=2010>2010</option>
            <option value=2011>2011</option>
            <option value=2012>2012</option>
            <option value=2013>2013</option>
            <option value=2014>2014</option>
            <option value=2015>2015</option>
            <option value=2016>2016</option>
            <option value=2017>2017</option>
            <option value=2018>2018</option>
            <option value=2019>2019</option>
            <option value=2020>2020</option>
            <option value=2021>2021</option>
            <option value=2022>2022</option>
            <option value=2023>2023</option>
            <option value=2024>2024</option>
            <option value=2025>2025</option>
            <option value=2026>2026</option>
            <option value=2027>2027</option>
            <option value=2028>2028</option>
            <option value=2029>2029</option>
            <option value=2030>2030</option>
        </select></form><br><br>
  
        <textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button id="button">Klick</button>
    </div>
</div>




<!--<button name="jump" onclick="jump()">Go</button>-->
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Optional JavaScript for bootstrap -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





</body>
</html>
```

when entering text, the text appears directly next to the date. what do i have to do to make 
the text appear one line below
would be nice if someone could post the correct code

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: Put a `<br>` tag where you want the row to break.

Comment: @Olian04 it doesnt wok

Comment: Try `e1.innerHTML += "<br>" + document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;`

Comment: @obscure it works men thanks a lot  :)

Comment: No problem AlKurdi - glad I could help! =)